# jquery displaying string of dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this part of my html that needs to display text of my dropdown

```
<select size="1" name="browser" class="customer">
    <option value="" selected="default" disabled="default">Select a customer</option>
    <option value="Mainstreet 1   1234AB   PlacePlace">Bert de Vries</option>
    <option value="Mainstreet2   5678CD   place">Bert de Bruijn</option>
    <option value="Mainstreet 3   9101EF   Place">Jan de Reud</option>
    <option value="MainStreet 4">Bertje de Gruun</option>
    <option value="Mainstreet5">Kees de Blouw</option>
    <option value="Mainstreet6">Gijs de Vras</option>
</select>
<label>Street:</label>
<input type="text" id="After" size="40" readonly>
```

and my jquery I have is this

```
$("#Customer").change(function () {
    var klantnr = $('#Customer option:selected').text();
    $.each($("#Customer"), function () {
        $("#After").val(klantnr);
    });
});
```

for some reason I do not get the value of my selected dropdown.

Comment: at least you have no element with id `Customer`

Answer (score 1):

The Customer is a class not an ID

```
$(".customer").change( function () {
  var klantnr = $('.customer option:selected').text();
  $.each($(".customer"), function () {
    $("#After").val(klantnr);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".customer").change( function () {
     var klantnr = $('.customer option:selected').text();
     $.each($(".customer"), function () {
        $("#After").val(klantnr);
     });
});
```

"customer" is a class not an id.